# Quarter display in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am struggling with a requirement to display quarterly data.
I created a disconnected table to filter quarters as below with index column using
DAX:  Index = RANKX('Parameter Table','Parameter Table'[Year Quarter],,ASC,Dense)

My requirement is as below:

When I select 2021Q4 it should display previous all years Q4 data including 2021Q4.
Ex:

```
2021Q4
2020Q4
2019Q4
2018Q4
```

When I select 2021Q3 it should display 2021Q3 and previous years Q4 data. same logic for Q2 or Q1 as well.
Ex:

```
2021Q3
2020Q4
2019Q4
2018Q4
```

Sample date:

```
Year    Quarter Country Value
2018    Q4  America 10
2018    Q4  Australia   15
2018    Q4  UK  20
2019    Q1  America 25
2019    Q2  Australia   30
2019    Q3  UK  35
2019    Q4  America 40
2019    Q1  America 45
2019    Q2  Australia   50
2019    Q3  America 55
2019    Q4  UK  60
2020    Q1  America 65
2020    Q2  America 70
2020    Q3  Australia   75
2020    Q4  America 80
2021    Q1  UK  85
2021    Q2  America 90
2021    Q3  America 95
2021    Q4  Australia   100
2022    Q1  UK  105
2022    Q1  America 110
```